# Get attributes of model in init at behavior yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Here is my code:

```
class CalculatedFieldsBehavior extends Behavior {
    public $calcFields = array();

    public function events() {
        return [
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_INIT => 'init',
        ];
    }

    public function init() {
        foreach ($this->owner->attributes() as $attribute) {
            if (strpos($attribute, 'calc_')) {
                if (!is_function(get_parent_class()::$set . \yii\helpers\camelize($attribute))) {
                    throw Exception("Function to set value of calc field '" . $attribute . "' not defined.");
                }

                $calcFields[] = $attribute;
            }
        }

        if (!($this->owner->hasAttribute('isCalcValueSet'))) {
            throw Exception("This table is missing a field for isCalcValueSet");
        }

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

And give this error:

> ```
> "name": "Exception",
> "message": "Call to a member function attributes() on null",
> "code": 0,
> "type": "Error",
> "file": "D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backoffice\\common\\models\\CalculatedFieldsBehavior.php",
> "line": 25,
> ```

Comment: Can you move parent::init(); to first line of init() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$owner` is not available in `init()`. It is set in [`attach()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-behavior#attach()-detail). Usually workflow looks like this:

```
$behavior = new MyBehavior(); // init() is called here
$behavior->attach($owner); // owner is set here
```

You should probably overwrite `attach()` in your case:

```
public function attach($owner) {
    foreach ($owner->attributes() as $attribute) {
        if (strpos($attribute, 'calc_')) {
            if (!is_function(get_parent_class()::$set . \yii\helpers\camelize($attribute))) {
                throw Exception("Function to set value of calc field '" . $attribute . "' not defined.");
            }

            $calcFields[] = $attribute;
        }
    }

    if (!($owner->hasAttribute('isCalcValueSet'))) {
        throw Exception("This table is missing a field for isCalcValueSet");
    }

    parent::attach($owner);
}
```